# How to specify the order of when values were input in a database without using time?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Difficult to make a title for this. Better explanation:

I am making a database to track match making rating in a game. If the user inputs, for example, 3500 as their rating, and then a second as 3600 and saves their input. Then when they realise that they have missed an input (3550), they wish to input this as having been inbetween the 2 other games. So that the system realises that they didn't increase by 100 then fall by 50, but instead increased just by 50 each time.

I do not wish to use time for this, due to the fact that I do not wish the user to have to remember the time of the games. Instead, I would prefer to use order. Thus, I was thinking this:

The database has a column entitled `Match_Order` or something. This is a unique value that increments by 1 with every user input. When the user decides that they wish to input a value in between the two matches, they specify (along with normal input) which `Match_Order` this is. For example saying `2`. Would this be possible? In effect inserting this value, and incrementing all larger values by 1? Otherwise, is there a better way that I can do this?

Extra info: The user inputs the data themselves from a webpage, entering their `Hero` `Match_ID` and `MMR` (match making rating).

Comment: Is an auto_increment column what you are looking for?

Comment: @mboldt I am not sure, is it? In that sense my question would be how I could input data that is lower than the highest value in the auto_increment column? Would that just increment all the other higher values by one? If so then I think that could be my solution. As I have said I haven't made the database yet. I am trying to figure this before I do!

Comment: I read your question again combined with your comment and realized I did not understand your question correctly earlier. So it seems like auto increment is not the right solution since you would not be able to insert values inbetween. However I did not come up with a better solution than the the one you proposed. Is it really necessary, to have the matches ordered like that? It sounds like you might have to do a lot of reordering manually if you insert a match inbetween two matches.

Comment: @mboldt No worries. No-one else has replied!

I'm not sure. The problem is that there is a heavy importance between games being in order, as the data needs to see how the MMR has changed between matches. I am wanting to include this as a safety measure. If someone realises that they have missed a game, they can enter it 'in between' the other matches, so to speak. Rather than deleting all games that are 'after' that game. Not sure how to do it!

Comment: But I'm thinking chances are if they don't know when they played a game, they might not really remember the exact order either. The problem is if you have 50 games in your database and you add a game between the first and the second, you will have to reorder all other games 3-50 aswell. I don't know exactly what you are trying to do but maybe you can just calculate the MMR change over a whole day? Then the exact order would not be that important.